# Display Flash Banner in Hippo Cms Site

Tags: java, hippocms

I am customizing the go green site , here I want to display a flash banner in the header part.

For this I did the following

1. In the hst:channelinfo added new property (headerFlashBanner) and
   path for that (/content/assets/Flash/2010/windymobility.flv).
2. In the WebsiteInfo.java added the following code :

   ```
       @Parameter(name = "headerFlashBanner")
       @JcrPath(
                pickerInitialPath = "/content/assets/Flash/2010"
               )
       String getHeaderFlashBannerPath();
   ```
3. In `WebsiteLogo.java` I did the following:

   Fetched the  flash doc path with the WebsiteInfo object

   final String headerFlashBannerPath = info.getHeaderFlashBannerPath();

Here I did an `System.out` to print banner path but it is not showing any path  and no exception is occuring.

Please help me how I can display the flash banner on my website.

Please mention what's need to do for displaying flash banner on website.What will be the code changes or what new classes I need to create.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a System.out in this case will reach the console, better to use a logger or set a breakpoint and check the value.

What you could do is put the path on the request. In your jsp you can then put the tags for displaying the flash. Actually you probably want to put the url on the path not the repository path. Or you can use the hst:link tag.